# Odoo Arabic Translation.

Tags: odoo-8, code-translation, po

In Odoo 8 , To do the translation from English to Arabic. I have did the following steps but could not achieve.

Settings -> Translations -> Load a Translation

Created a record with Arabic

Then Changed the preference to Arabic.

The view will be changed in Arabic.

Question 1. There are some default fields, which is not translating.
Question 2. If it is translated, If I changed the view in XML. It again becomes in English
Question 3. It is not getting translated for newly created modules.

If It is all to do with .PO files.
How to generate a .PO file automatically for newly created module.
What is the command line to generate your .po file
Kindly suggest good idea to create .po files and above questions.

Comment: I imported .PO files from Administration/Translations/ Import / Export. I got .po file with all my field names. Here in this file **msgid** , the field name will be there. and I have to type the respective translation in **msgstr**. It is long process. Any more good suggestions...????

Comment: I have a .po files with all in english,i want the respective **msgstr**, to be converted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The translation is based on **i18n** folder of your module. You can create a new translations using **poedit**.

If the translation is already done and You have changed in .po file but not updating

To get this.

In query

```
delete from ir_translation where module = 'Your_module_name'
```

or

```
delete from ir_translation where src like '%your_field_name%'
```

Above will delete all the existing translated fields, based on the where clause.

Then In settings.

[image: Load an Translation]

On clicking on the Load button, the new translation values will be appeared.